# exchange 2010 - all employees group

Tags: exchange, email-server, exchange-2010

Since the beginning of our exchange - we have a group called all employees. everyone is included in it and it sends email to everyone.

I can't edited the settings of it using the management console and it tells me it is built it.

we want to remove a few people from the all employees mailing list.
is this possible? or do i have to create a new mailing list, disable the all employees and setup my custom filters for the new mailing list?

thanks

Comment: 'everyone' means exactly that. You can't do "everyone" except for Bob and Jane.

Comment: @draeath There is no builtin distribution group of that name.  As KContreau suggests, someone has likely has set the Domain Users group up with a display name of All Employees.  The reason he can't remove users is most likely due to the Domain User group being their primary group. So technically you could say "everyone" except for Bob and Jane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect they renamed a built-in group. Create a new group and add the employees there.

Comment: that is what i was thinking of doing and creating new filters for the new group to exclude a few users.